# Flutter Sqlite Query Error data fetch Error

Tags: flutter

When I run Query fetch Details with two conditions? getting error

Unhandled Exception:

> DatabaseException(near "2019": syntax error (code 1):

, while compiling: `SELECT monthyear FROM metersd WHERE shopid=1 AND monthyear =  August 2019) sql 'SELECT monthyear FROM metersd WHERE shopid=1 AND monthyear =  August 2019' args []}`

```
SELECT monthyear FROM metersd WHERE shopid=1 AND monthyear =  August 2019

Future<MeterData> getMonthYear(int uid,String month) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var result = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT monthyear FROM $table WHERE $shopid=$uid AND $monthyear = $month");

    if (result.length == 0) return null;
    return MeterData.fromMap(result.first);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT monthyear FROM $table WHERE $shopid=$uid AND 
 $monthyear="+"'$month'",null)
```

Add just single qoute in logic query when 'condition1' and 'condition2'

```
Future<MeterData> getMonthYear(int uid,String month) async {
var dbClient = await db;
var result = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT monthyear FROM $table WHERE $shopid=$uid AND $monthyear="+"'$month'",null);

if (result.length == 0) return null;
return MeterData.fromMap(result.first);
}
```